# cx-freeze "ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application"

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, pyqt, cx-freeze

I am getting an error after I install a python/pyqt/matplotlib app that I freeze with cx-freeze. 
I build the app with

```
python setup.py build
```

setup.py is this

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable
buildOptions = dict(packages = [], excludes = [])
import sys
base = 'Win32GUI' if sys.platform=='win32' else None
executables = [
    Executable('SectionPropertyCalculator.py', base=base)
]
setup(name='Mecanica-SectionPropertyCalculator',
      version = '0.1',
      description = 'SPC is a GUI to calculate geometrical properties of beam profiles.',
      options = dict(build_exe = buildOptions),
      executables = executables)
```

I get

```
Mecanica-SectionPropertyCalculator-0.1-amd64.exe
```

The .exe runs ok on my dev machine

Then I create a msi installer with

```
cx-freeze app bdist_msi
```

I get

```
Mecanica-SectionPropertyCalculator-0.1-amd64.msi
```

I install it into another machine with same OS, i5 processor, etc. and I get an error

```
File "C:\...SpcPlotQt.py", line 4 in <module> 
ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application
```

Now, SpcPlotQt.py is my code and on line 4 I have

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QDialog, QApplication
```

I have PyQt5.5.13.2 installed with pip3 (everything 64 bit) and I am pretty sure I installed python 3.7 x64, which I confirm by

```
import struct; print( 8 * struct.calcsize("P"))
64
```

Also, if I run

```
import sys; print("%x" % sys.maxsize, sys.maxsize > 2**32)
True
```

and

```
import ctypes; print (ctypes.sizeof(ctypes.c_voidp))
8
```

and

```
import platform; platform.architecture()[0]
64bit
```

and

```
import os; os.environ["PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE"]
AMD64
```

All 5 tests above tells that everything is 64 bit.

But when I run

```
import sys; print (sys.platform)
win32
```

Why?

AND... cx-freeze scripts use sys.platform to decide what base to use, thus it chooses

```
base=Win32GUI
```

What should I do?

I notice that `python setup.py build` runs out of a cmd shell, which is always 32 bit, no matter how I open it; even a PowerShell is 32 bit. Could this be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In 90% of cases this error is the result of some mixing of 64bit and 32bit. Assuming all your tests here are accurate, I'm guessing the dev machine you are using has everything at 64bit, but the other windows machine either has a DLL that was desinged for 32 bit, or the windows system itself is a 32bit installation (even if the machine itself is 64 bit).

Don't worry about `sys.platform` returning `win32`, that's what it does.

Try the basics on both machines: right click on `computer` in the file explorer and then `properties` - see if the installation of windows is 32 or 64 bit. If the other machine is 32 bit, then your exe isn't compatible with it unless you're willing to change the OS.

An alternative solution: install the python 32 bit version on your dev machine, making the exe file with it pretty much guarantees that it will work on both 32 and 64 bit system.

Comment: I followed your advice, installed 32 bit python, created a venv-32 for that, and pip installed everything else. Now the .exe runs in both machines but the bdist_msi fails at the end, right when is trying to write the .msi file. Maybe I should start another question?

Comment: Did you attempt making an exe with the 32 bit version of python?

Comment: Yes, now it works, with everything in 32 bits, it builds the .exe, then the .msi, then I installed the app on the test computer! success! It is a pity that there is a snag in the 64 version, but I could not find it.

Comment: About `sys.platform`... cx_freeze developers use it to select the `base`. Since `sys.platform` is wrong, the base is wrong. Maybe cx_freeze developers can solve this problem? how do we report this bug?